# AngularJS ng-repeat default value does not work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I am working with AngularJS and I am so new in that.

My aim is fill a tag SELECT  with OPTION element from a datasource.
That is what I do basically:

```
<script>

    function LocalizationController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.Regions = [
            { ID: "001", DESC: "DESC_1" },
              { ID: "002", DESC: "DESC_2" },
                 { ID: "003", DESC: "DESC_3" },
                    { ID: "004", DESC: "DESC_4" },
        ];

        $scope.Region = "003";
        $scope.init = function () {
            $scope.Region = "003";
        }
    }
</script>


<div ng-controller="LocalizationController" ng-init="init();">
    <input type="button" ng-click="Region='002'" value="test">
    <select id="region" name="RegionCode" ng-model="Region">
        <option ng-repeat="item in Regions" value="{{item.ID}}">{{item.DESC}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Everything works good, the Select is fill of my items,
but I would like to set default value.

How you can see 
 - I set  my object model which is ng-model="Region"
 - I set its default value into init() function by $scope.Region = "003";
when the SELECT is loaded I do not why but dafault value is the first one "001"

I also tried to change value manually by 

in that case the SELECT gets the right value selection.

Anyone can explain why it does not work?

I know that is a common problem, I am already looked for that,
any solution suggestion to use NG-OPTION, that directive works good,
it can fill my SELECT with my array of object, it can select default  value,
very nice but it does not solve my problem because the value into the 
the option element id an integer autoincrement which is not what I want.

so in summary:

NG-REPEAT can render the SELECT how I want but default value does not  work
NG-OPTIONS can render the SELECT how I want, default value works but the value into option 
item cannot be set how I want.

any suggestions?

thanks  in advance

---

EDIT

---

I found a "solution"

```
<div ng-controller="LocalizationController" EXCLUDE-ng-init="init();"> 
     <select id="region" onload="alert();angular.element(this).scope().Region='002'"  name="RegionCode" ng-model="Region">
        <option ng-repeat="item in Regions" value="{{item.ID}}">{{item.DESC}}</option>
         {{init();}}
    </select>
</div>
```

I do not  like so much but works pretty good:
 -  ng-init="init();" does not work good 
 - If we exclude the initialize of default value into ng-init so EXCLUDE-ng-init="init();" and put the initilize when option are loded it works

Have a look at the code  blow, I put {{init();}} after ng-repeat. Everithing works good
  {{item.DESC}}
             {{init();}}

I do not think is the best  solution but Works, 
1) I have a droopdown fill of my elements
2) The value of option into my list is CORRECT, "001", "002" and not a stupid autoincremental value which is useless.

I hope that can help someone... 
THANKS TO EVERYONE TRIED TO HELP ME

---

Comment: Why don't you use `ng-options` with `track by` expression?

Comment: The main problem to use NG-OPTIONS is into the server side code, 
I will not get the right value which I want. 
How we know the select tag which is loaded by ng-option gets as value an auto incremental integer... and  that is  not useful..
My value is and alphanumeric value, and anyway I could need a value which is not auto incremental.. so NG-OPTIONS is not a good solusion

NG-REPEAT is the most flexible solution but I cannot get why default 
value cannot be set into ng-init function() :-\

thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use ng-options

```
<select id="region" name="RegionCode" ng-model="Region" ng-options="option.ID as option.DESC for option in Regions">
```

And do

```
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.Region = $scope.Regions[2];
}
```

When you inspect the select box while using `ng-options` the values for the options will be like 0,1,2,3.., that is auto increment integer as you said. But don't worry about that. Its the value just for showing up there, but once you post your form you will get the right value as you possess, in your case `ID`.

Comment: I have just tried what you said,
in server side code the value it is still  the autoincremental value,
Just to add info:
- I have tried by ajax submit with  $("#myForm").serialize()
- I have tried clasic html submit
Nothing change the value into server it is the autoincrfemental value..

Comment: Why you are using ajax submit if angular has got a method to handle the form submission?

Comment: The page where I am working it already built with JQuery,
part of this page has  three dropdown select option with 
NATION, REGION CITY
Since I would to introduce AngularJS to improve the project 
I thought was good make a controller where to manage Nation,Region and City, also because this three droopdown are placed  in more than 
one page.

then I cannot change the form submition because is done and tested
do you think ajax jquery submition could be make a problem to get the real value of option back ?

Comment: If you are using ajax form submission you can't use ng-options. You have to use ng-repeat as you are doing now.

Comment: I got that, but I cannot get why it is hard select a defualt value by ng-repeat... Everytime I try it is always selected the first element of "select ooptions".

At moment i solved using :
- ng-option to set a right default value 
- angular.element("#region").scope().Region to get that value
- $.post(params) classic JQuery post
thanks

Answer (score 0):

use **ng-options**

and in this case if you play with object (not single values) it should be so

```
$scope.init = function () {
    $scope.Region = $scope.Regions[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer, but how I remarked more the once, 
ng-options is not a completly solution..
it makes autoincremental value which is useless..

thanks anyway for your  interest...